# Знаки препинания при выражении "почему бы и нет"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли как-либо выделять (запятой или тире, например) сочетание "почему бы и нет"?

Примеры предложений:

- Ради денег почему бы и нет?
- Он подумал почему бы и нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы так оформил:

- Ради денег — почему бы и нет?
- Он подумал: "А почему бы и нет?"

В тире не совсем уверен и обосновать не смогу, а со вторым примером, надеюсь, понятно.